# Qweb/odoo 9-Convert datetime to time

Tags: odoo, odoo-9, qweb

How to Convert datetime to time in qweb report. Now return **2016-11-03 07:40:55** I want only  **07:40:55**

My solution is not working:

```
<span t-esc="o.start" t-field-options='{"format": "hh.mm.ss"}'/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `t-esc` to `t-field`. `t-field-options` only works on `t-field`.